# Programatically created OpenXml XLSX file contents are not displayed in the open office but can be viewed in MS Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openoffice.org

I have created an xlsx file in Documentformat.openxml library using c#. The resulting file can be view in Excel but cannot view in open office. Is the results blank in open office?

Comment: Have you tried LibreOffice?  If that doesn't work, then perhaps you should use a different library that is designed to work with both MS Office and LibreOffice.

Comment: Can you make a small example and open the XLSX file with notepad, and add the raw xml to your question (above).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make the issue reproducible: describe versions of the used software, an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve code that creates a problematic document and also add XML of the created document like tgolisch has suggested. Without this it's hard to help you. Best regards